# jquery animate doesn't working with rgba

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color, rgba

I'm trying to animate div using jquery. I want to do a button from the div which change his opacity on hover:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.zprava_link').hover(
    function() {
         $(this).stop().animate(backgroundColor: 'rgba(121, 202, 199, 1.0)', 0);
    },
    function() {
         $(this).stop().animate(backgroundColor: 'rgba(121, 202, 199, 0.7)', 800);
    });

  });
```

my div:

```
.zprava_link{
width:42px;
height:100%;
position: absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;            
background-color: rgba(121, 202, 199, 0.7);
}
```

and usage in HTML:

```
<div class="zprava_link" id="">
  <table>
  <tr><td><a href=""><img src="images/rarr.png"></a></td></tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

I also link newest versions of jquery library and jquery.color library, but it doesn't work, script doesn't start. It may seems, that script isn't good, but it is. I'm afraid, that it's some "not support" bug. I'm using Firefox 27/Opera 12.

Does anybody know, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Have you tried animating the opacity or using `fadeTo()`?

Comment: yes, but it takes 0.7 opacity like 1.0 opacity.

Comment: Try with this plugin: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: nothing changed, sorry :(

Comment: Why the id is empty? You should atleast give it some value or id tag should be removed

Comment: Because i had some stuff there before... but it could not affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with just CSS, by using [CSS transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)

```
.zprava_link {
    width:42px;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    transition:background-color 0.8s;
    background-color: rgba(121, 202, 199, 0.7);
}
.zprava_link:hover{
    background-color:rgba(121, 202, 199, 1);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vGtGL/

---

To only have the animation on the *hover-out* set the duration on the `:hover` rule

```
.zprava_link:hover{
    transition-duration:0s;
    background-color:rgba(121, 202, 199, 1);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vGtGL/1/

Comment: yes, I know, I've tried it before, but I don't want same time before and after hover, I want 0s when cursor is over div and 0.8 when cursor goes out of the div.

Comment: @user3352323 then just reset the  `transition-duration` property on the `:hover` rule.

Comment: yes, that helped a lot. And brought me to the whole new world of css transitions ;) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot animate colours by default. In order to animate colours, use the official [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin.

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

Comment: I said I'm using jquery color plugin ;)

Comment: scriptdoes'ntstart: include colour plugin after jquery library

Comment: That script worked well until I started to play with alpha channel. Script can be broken, but I don't think that.

Comment: if you aware of jquery NoConflict use that, it may be the reason